# Need help comparing an integer to a string

Tags: c++, arrays

I have to create a phone book for this assignment.  For this particular function I have to find people with the same area code.

I pass in the area code as an integer.  However the phone number as a whole is saved as part of an array into a string. I need help finding the proper method of traversing the array and comparing the two.

For this example, I try to turn the passed in area code into a string and then see if the area code is in the string using the find function.  I have also tried using a compare function and have not seen any success.

```
void printPersonsHavingSameAreaCodePhoneNum(addressBookType addressBook[], 
int numOfAddress, int areaCode){



cout << "List of Names who have phone number with area code: " << areaCode 
<< endl;

bool found = false;

stringstream ss;
ss << areaCode <<endl;

string areaCodeString=ss.str();

 for(int i=0;i<numOfAddress;i++){
    if(addressBook[i].getPhoneNumber().find(areaCodeString)){
        addressBook[i].print();
        found=true;
    }
 }

  if(!found){
    cout << "No Records found!" << endl;
    cout << "- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -" <<  endl;
  }


}
```

No error message occurs, it just says that No records were found even though that should not be true with the data I was given.

Comment: `std::to_string(areaCode)` will give you a string that you can use to compare with other strings. Also, instead of having a C style array of `addressBookType`, use `std::vector<addressBookType>` to avoid having to send `numOfAddress` with it etc.

Comment: We are supposed to use arrays on this assignment.  :/

Comment: Ok, then use `std::array`. It seems odd to use arrays (both C style and `std::array`)  for this though. You can't dynamically add to such an array. Its size must be known at compiletime.

Comment: `std::array` is not an array, it's a structure containing an array.  `addressBookType addressBook[]` is not an array either, when used as a parameter it's actually a pointer.

Comment: Note that your approach of "find the area code **anywhere** in the phone number string" will give false positives.  You need to compare the area code to just the area code portion, not the exchange or local portion (or crossing the boundaries thereof, if the phone number isn't stored with separators).

Comment: you are not using areaCodeString in find call. 
if(addressBook[i].getPhoneNumber().find(areaCode)){

Comment: sorry, yeah I must have type it out wrong in here but even when i use find(areaCodeString) im not getting anything back

Comment: validate areaCode value and addressBook values by debug messages. Or run the program in debug mode and check the values in the find call.

Comment: You can convert an integer to a string by using `std::ostringstream`.  You can convert a number in text format to an integer by using `std::stoul`.  Compares are easier when both items are in the same format (and have the same type).